# wxBufferedPaintDC (Device Context) Trouble with wxPython onPaint event handler

Tags: python, events, handler, wxwidgets

I have a class called `imageBrowser` that displays an image in a `wxMDIChildFrame`.  This class is mainly for displaying an image to the user with a set of controls to browse through the image set.  Now, in this class I have overridden the `onPaint` event handler to respond to the controls attached to this `wxMDIChildFrame`.  So there are two checkboxes on the `imageBrowser`: one for a grid overlay and another for a scalebar overlay.  When checked, the DC draws the grid on top of the image or the scale bar.  These methods work fine.  The problem occurs when I check off another checkbox in a seperate `wxMDIChildFrame` to draw some random dots over the image, the grid and scalebar disappear immediatly upon checking this checkbox.  However, if I just resize the `imageBrowser`, `wxMDIChildFrame`, the grid, scalebar, and dots all appear. So here is my `onPaint` handler:

```
def OnPaint(self, event):
    dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self.staticBitmap, self.staticBitmap.GetBitmap())
    dc.Clear()
    dc.DrawBitmap(self.wxBitmap, 0, 0)
    self.drawScaleBar(dc)
    self.drawGrid(dc)
    self.drawDots(dc)
    event.Skip()

def drawGrid(self, dc):
    gridWid, gridHgt = self.staticBitmap.GetBitmap().GetSize()
    numRows, numCols = self.gridSize, self.gridSize
    if self.controlPanel.showGridBox.IsChecked():
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(self.gridColor, self.gridThickness))
        dc.SetTextForeground(self.gridColor)
        cellWid = float( gridWid - 1) / numRows
        cellHgt = float( gridHgt - 1) / numCols
        for rowNum in xrange( numRows + 1) :
            dc.DrawLine( 0, rowNum*cellHgt, gridWid, rowNum*cellHgt )
        for colNum in xrange( numCols + 1 ) :
            dc.DrawLine( colNum*cellWid, 0, colNum*cellWid, gridHgt )


def drawScaleBar(self, dc):
    gridWid, gridHgt = self.wxBitmap.GetSize()
    if self.controlPanel.showScaleBar.IsChecked():
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(self.scaleColor, 2))
        dc.SetTextForeground(self.scaleColor)
        width = self.Tools.imageInfo.size.GetLabel().split()[1]
        #Scales the bar to the image width.  If the user selected scale is larger than
        #the current image the scale is set to the maximum width of the image.
        if width != 'None':
            width = width.replace('m', '')
            width = float(width)
            lineSize = ((gridWid/width) * (self.scaleSize/100.0))
            if lineSize > gridWid:
                lineSize = (gridWid * 0.9) - 1
                self.scaleSize = int(width * 100 - 10)
                self.controlPanel.chooseScaleSize.SetValue(str(self.scaleSize))
                self.drawScaleBar(dc)
            elif self.scaleLoc == 'Top Left':
                dc.DrawLine(10, gridHgt * 0.1, 10 + lineSize, gridHgt * 0.1)
                dc.DrawLine(10, gridHgt * 0.1 + 10, 10, gridHgt * 0.1 - 10)
                dc.DrawLine(10 + lineSize, gridHgt * 0.1 + 10, 10 + lineSize, gridHgt * 0.1 - 10)
                dc.DrawText(str(self.scaleSize) + 'cm', (10 + 10 + lineSize)/2.0 - 15, gridHgt * 0.1 - 25)
            elif self.scaleLoc == 'Top Right':
                dc.DrawLine(gridWid - 10, gridHgt * 0.1, (gridWid - 10) - lineSize, gridHgt * 0.1)
                dc.DrawLine(gridWid - 10, gridHgt * 0.1 + 10, gridWid - 10, gridHgt * 0.1 - 10)
                dc.DrawLine((gridWid - 10) - lineSize, gridHgt * 0.1 + 10, (gridWid - 10) - lineSize, gridHgt * 0.1 - 10)
                dc.DrawText(str(self.scaleSize) + 'cm', ((gridWid - 10 - lineSize)+(gridWid - 10))/2.0 - 20, gridHgt * 0.1 - 25)
            elif self.scaleLoc == 'Bottom Left':
                dc.DrawLine(10, gridHgt * 0.9, 10 + lineSize, gridHgt * 0.9)
                dc.DrawLine(10, gridHgt * 0.9 + 10, 10, gridHgt * 0.9 - 10)
                dc.DrawLine(10 + lineSize, gridHgt * 0.9 + 10, 10 + lineSize, gridHgt * 0.9 - 10)
                dc.DrawText(str(self.scaleSize) + 'cm', (10 + 10 + lineSize)/2.0 - 15, gridHgt * 0.9 - 25)
            elif self.scaleLoc == 'Bottom Right':
                dc.DrawLine(gridWid - 10, gridHgt * 0.9, (gridWid - 10) - lineSize, gridHgt * 0.9)
                dc.DrawLine(gridWid - 10, gridHgt * 0.9 + 10, gridWid - 10, gridHgt * 0.9 - 10)
                dc.DrawLine((gridWid - 10) - lineSize, gridHgt * 0.9 + 10, (gridWid - 10) - lineSize, gridHgt * 0.9 - 10)
                dc.DrawText(str(self.scaleSize) + 'cm', ((gridWid - 10 - lineSize)+(gridWid - 10))/2.0 - 20, gridHgt * 0.9 - 25)
        else:
            #If there is no depth or size information for the current image the scale
            #bar is collapsed and '0cm' is displayed.
            if self.scaleLoc == 'Top Left':
                dc.DrawLine((15) + (gridWid/15), gridHgt * 0.1 + 10, (15) + (gridWid/15), gridHgt * 0.1 - 10)
                dc.DrawText('0cm', (15) + (gridWid/15/2), gridHgt * 0.1 - 25)
            elif self.scaleLoc == 'Top Right':
                dc.DrawLine((gridWid * 0.9) - (gridWid/15), gridHgt * 0.1 + 10, (gridWid * 0.9) - (gridWid/15), gridHgt * 0.1 - 10)
                dc.DrawText('0cm', (gridWid * 0.9) - (gridWid/15), gridHgt * 0.1 - 25)
            elif self.scaleLoc == 'Bottom Left':
                dc.DrawLine((15) + (gridWid/15), gridHgt * 0.9 + 10, (15) + (gridWid/15), gridHgt * 0.9 - 10)
                dc.DrawText('0cm', (15) + (gridWid/15/2), gridHgt * 0.9 - 25)
            elif self.scaleLoc == 'Bottom Right':
                dc.DrawLine((gridWid * 0.9) - (gridWid/15), gridHgt * 0.9 + 10, (gridWid * 0.9) - (gridWid/15), gridHgt * 0.9 - 10)
                dc.DrawText('0cm', (gridWid * 0.9) - (gridWid/15), gridHgt * 0.9 - 25)

def drawDots(self, dc):
    if self.Tools.classificationTool.dotEnable.GetValue():
        for dictionary in Workspace.assignmentHash:
            if dictionary.keys()[0] == Workspace.data.getImageName(Workspace.currentImageIndex):
                dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('Red', 1))
                dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush('Red'))
                print 'This image should have Dots!'
                index = Workspace.assignmentHash.index(dictionary)
                for dict in Workspace.assignmentHash[index].values()[0]:
                    s = dict.keys()[0]
                    r = re.search('(d\d+)(\(\d.\d+,\d.\d+\))', s)
                    num = r.group(1)[1:]
                    coord = r.group(2).split(',')
                    x = float(coord[0][1:])
                    x *= (Workspace.iWidth*Workspace.zoomScale)
                    x = int(x)
                    y = float(coord[1][:-1])
                    y *= (Workspace.iHeight*Workspace.zoomScale)
                    y = int(y)
                    dc.DrawCircle(x, y, 3)
```

Again, this works fine as long as the checkbox for drawDots (located on a different `wxMDIChildFrame`) is not enabled.  It is important to note that this other `wxMDIChildFrame` initially loads as just a blank Frame.  The user then opens a 'Classification File' that destroys that initial blank frame, removes its initial menu from the menu bar and then re-initializes it with widgets based on the 'classification file' and then adds the menu back into the menubar with additional options.  It is only after this 'classification file' has been opened that the checkbox clears the grid/scalebar.

I implemented the `drawDots()` method the same way I implimented the `drawGrid()` and `drawScaleBar()`.  The only difference is that the checkbox for `drawDots()` is in a different class.  The event handler for this checkbox does literally nothing except make a call to a parent class that forces a re-paint event by calling another method that uses `Refresh()`. This is the way that the `drawScaleBar()` and `drawGrid()` methods do it as well.

How can I fix this problem?